# How to interpret the complex index of refraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, refraction, complex-numbers

The index of refraction which represents how much light gets refracted when entering a medium is defined as

$$n = \frac{c}{v}$$

I have seen it stated in several places, such as [here](http://physics.wikia.com/wiki/Refractive_index), that we can replace the index of refraction with a complex index of refraction

$$\tilde{n} = n + ik$$

I don't understand how we can do this and what it actually represents. Either the index of refraction is complex valued or not, I don't see how you can just arbitrarily replace a real valued variable with a complex valued variable. So how is this valid?

Also, in the link above it states that $k$ represents the absorption loss. Why is a complex number needed to represent this?

Comment: How much do you know about complex numbers? e.g. That $\exp [i(n + ik)x]$ would be the product of an oscillatory function and an exponential decay. Closely related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108580/

Comment: If the general solution to a differential equation is $y = \exp (\alpha x)$, there is nothing to stop you making $\alpha$ a complex number. You may have met an example in damped harmonic motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electromagnetic theory combined with optics gives an electromagnetic interpretation for the refractive index:
$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}\sqrt{\epsilon_r\mu_r}} = 
\frac{c}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r\mu_r}} = \frac{c}{n}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
n^2 = \epsilon_r\mu_r
$$

If we ignore magnetic properties, ie $\mu_r\approx 1$, then we have: $n^2 = \epsilon_r$. If you solve maxwell equations for an waving electromagnetic field in vacuum, you will get this result for plane waves: $\mathbf k\times\mathbf B = -\omega/c^2\epsilon_r\mathbf E$. The form of the $\mathbf{E}$ plane wave is:
$$\mathbf E = \mathbf E_0 e^{i(\omega t - \mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r)}$$

But, then, when you plug an electromagnetic plane wave into the Maxwell Equations for a non-magnetic material with conductivity $\sigma$ and relative complex permittivity $ \hat{\epsilon}_r = \epsilon'+i\epsilon''$, the current is $\mathbf J_{\text{tot}} = J_{\text{displacement}} + J_{\text{conduction}} = i\omega\epsilon\mathbf E_0 + \sigma\mathbf E_0 = i\omega\epsilon_0(\epsilon' - \frac{i\sigma}{\epsilon_0 \omega})$ and the Ampere Equation reduces to:
$$
-i\mathbf k\times\mathbf B_0 = \frac{i\omega}{c^2}\left(\epsilon' - \frac{i\sigma}{\epsilon_0\omega}\right)\mathbf E_0
$$

Then, in comparison with previous result, we defined a complex dielectric constant:
$$
\hat\epsilon_r = \epsilon' + i\epsilon'' = \epsilon' - \frac{i\sigma}{\epsilon_0\omega}
$$

And then, we define a complex refraction index: $\hat n = n +i\kappa =  \sqrt{\hat\epsilon_r}$, $\frac{kc}{\omega} = \hat{n}$ with the branch chosen so that the real exponential is decaying. Assuming a plane wave propagating in the $+x$ direction, you now get a damped wave, where the complex part of the refraction index $\epsilon''$ makes the wave decrease its electric field exponentially:
$$
\mathbf E(x, t) = \mathbf E_0 e^{i \left( \omega t - kx \right)} = \mathbf E_0 e^{-\frac{\omega}{c}\kappa x}
e^{i\left(\omega t - \frac{\omega n}{c}x\right)}
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imaginary number for extinction coefficient in complex refractive index](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108580) or [How to interpret the complex index of refraction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213237)

Comment: @sammygerbil The first link you've sent, the answers has hardly any equations. The second link is this question itself. Well.. Out of curiosity.. what is the procedure when an answer is a duplicate? =D.

Comment: Sorry, I posted to the wrong question. Reviewers (rep > 3k) vote on whether one question is a duplicate of another. Usually the newer question is closed, unless it has more and better answers. I did not intend this question to be closed. I made a mistake switching between windows.

Comment: Nice interpretation! I think it’s quite remarkable that usually the *real* part is associated with loss and the imaginary part with just a phase shift (capacitors etc). In this case it’s reverse: The *imaginary* part causes loss